# Average of column for 15 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario where I need average of Usage column in 15 seconds and sum it up to one hour. for a particular MID,SID and PID, Now I'm doing it by increment a time loop by 15 seconds dateadd(second, 15, @StartTime) but this very slow. Please suggest a better solution.See the table below.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleData](
 [MID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [SID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [PID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Usage] [decimal](10, 4) NOT NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
enter code here
```

Sample data

```
INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A64500001068 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(27.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A645000020D0 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(40.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A64500003138 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(98.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A645000041A0 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(58.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A6450010CCC8 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(74.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A6450010DD30 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(42.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A6450010ED98 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(34.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A6450010FE00 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(36.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A64500218928 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(84.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A64500219990 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(19.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A6450021A9F8 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(40.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A6450021BA60 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(48.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A64500324588 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(97.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A645003255F0 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(48.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A64500326784 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(60.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([MID], [StartTime], [SID], [PID], [Usage]) VALUES (N'77', CAST(0x0000A64500327DC8 AS DateTime), 1, 1, CAST(48.0000 AS Decimal(10, 4)))
```

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would be helpful

Comment: Could you also add your current code that includes the loop.

Comment: Do you mean: average of Usage column **every** 15 seconds?

Comment: Yes every 15 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Inner SQL: Average value of `Usage` for each quarter of a minute (=15 Seconds) in a minute, in an hour, in a day, monthe and year.
- Outer SQL: Sum of the above average values, for each hour.

Inner SQL: average value of `Usage` for each quarter of a minute (=15 Seconds).

```
SELECT [MID], [SID], [PID], 
Yr, 
Mn,  
Dy,  
Hr
SUM(AvgUse) AS HourSumOfUse
FROM
(  
    SELECT [MID], [SID], [PID], 
    YEAR([StartTime]) AS Yr, 
    MONTH([StartTime]) AS Mn,  
    DAY([StartTime]) AS Dy,  
    DATEPART ("HH",[StartTime]) AS Hr,  
    DATEPART ("Mi", [StartTime]) AS Mn,  
    CAST(DATEPART ("ss", [StartTime])/15 + 1, Int) AS Q_Min,  
    Avg([Usage]) AS AvgUse 
    FROM [dbo].[SampleData]
    GROUP BY [MID], [SID], [PID], 
        YEAR([StartTime]),
        MONTH([StartTime]),
        DAY([StartTime]),  
        DATEPART ("HH",[StartTime]),  
        DATEPART ("Mi", [StartTime]),
        CAST(DATEPART ("ss", [StartTime])/15 + 1, Int) 
)
GROUP BY [MID], [SID], [PID], 
   Yr,
   Mn,
   Dy,
   Hr
```

Comment: In the same sample code I want to pick data according to dateTime i.e StartDate between (Select Max(Sdate) from MasteTbl), Please suggest a solution

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause in the inner SQL